# Amazon Neptune overwrites blank node values when inserting data

Tags: sparql, rdf, amazon-neptune, blank-nodes

When inserting a triple with a blank node into an Amazon Neptune instance:

```
INSERT DATA { <http://example.com/s> <http://example.com/p> _:something }
```

…the blank node's value gets replaced with `b<SOME NUMBER>`. Running a query like this:

```
SELECT ?o WHERE { <http://example.com/s> <http://example.com/p> ?o }
```

…will return something like this:

```json
{
    "results": {
        "bindings": [
            {
                "o": {
                    "type": "bnode",
                    "value": "b24508943"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to retain original blank node names when loading data into Neptune?

Comment: according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/load-api-reference-load.html I don't think so, at least I could find a "preserve blank node names" option or similar. Why do you need this?

Comment: Honestly, I'd ask such product specific qustions on a more related channel, e.g. their forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=253

Comment: There were the so-called "told bnodes" in Blazegraph: `com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.Options.STORE_BLANK_NODES`. Not sure these settings are accessible in Neptune.

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks, I've just reposted it there. Users sometimes need to use those original values in their queries. I do understand that the whole point of a blank node is anonimity, otherwise it should be an IRI, but I don't have control over the data, hence this question.

Comment: ok, yeah that's what I thought. Some of those corner case everybody got into. And I can see that somebody replied to your their in the AWS forum with the standard answer ... you should tell him that you're aware of the fact but nevertheless some other triple stores do support such an option, even the Amazon Neptune predecessor Blazegraph, among others. I'm sure he's not a Neptune developer though, so others might have "better" answers.

Comment: Something very similar happened to me recently! I wanted to retrieve some money back from my bank account but they couldn't give me the same bank-note back that I originally depositted! I understand an account is not a safe-box, but still! Users sometimes need the original bank-notes, there might be phone number writen on it. #abstractionsarehard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of blank nodes is that *they are not addressable* (from "outside"). If you need something you can address (i.e., "point to") later, you should give it a URI.

If you have a blank node that serves as the subject of some statements, you might be able to find those statements if some other statement uses that blank node as well (e.g., as its object). That is, you could use a query to find them. Otherwise, use a URI.